# T distribution with n degrees degrees of freedom

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I would like to prove that $\displaystyle \frac{\bar{X}\,\sqrt{n}\,}{\hat σ^2}\sim t_{n}$. 
 Note that x~N(0,$σ^2$) and they are iid.

---

Could someone explain why

$\displaystyle \frac{\bar{X}\,\sqrt{n}\,}{\hat σ^2}\sim t_{n}$ = $\displaystyle \frac{N(0,1){}\,\,}{\sqrt\frac{n\hat σ^2}{σ^2 /n } \ }$

After I reduce the first equation, I get

$\displaystyle \frac{N(0,1){}\,\,}{\hat σ^2/σ}$. Is there something wrong here?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Characterization). Btw, I think that $t_n$ should be $t_{n-1}$ in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $X_i$ follows $N(0,\sigma^2)$, $\Sigma_{i=0}^nX_i$ follows $N(0,n\sigma^2)$.
So $\bar{X}=\dfrac{\Sigma_{i=0}^nX_i}{n}$ follows $N(0,\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{n}}).$
Thus $\dfrac{\sqrt{n}\bar{X}}{\sigma^2}$ follows $N(0,1)$.

and $\dfrac{(n-1)s}{\sigma^2}$ follows $\chi_{n-1}^2$ and is independent of $\bar{X}$.
so $\dfrac{\sqrt{n}\bar{X}}{\sigma^2}/\dfrac{(n-1)s}{\sigma^2(n-1)}=\dfrac{\sqrt{n}\bar{X}}{s}$ follows $t_{n-1}$.

Comment: By $s$ I mean $\hat{\sigma^2}$, the unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Could you show the algebraic manipulations that you do?

Comment: Would be great if you also show why $\dfrac{(n-1)s}{\sigma^2}$ follows $\chi_{n-1}^2$ and is independent of $\bar{X}$ :-)

Comment: I am using Basu's theorem to say $\bar{X}$ and $s$ are independent.

Comment: To show $s$ is independent of $\bar{X}$ first show $(X_i-\bar{X})$ is independent of $\bar{X}$ using $\Sigma_{i=0}^na_iX_i$ and $\Sigma_{i=0}^nb_iX_i$ are independent if $\Sigma_{i=0}^na_ib_i=0$. so there sum-square are also independent.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\bar{X}$ may not be a standard normal. 
Your $X$ r.v. representing $t$-distribution $$X = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{U/n}}$$ where U = variance.
IF you have a copy of Mood Graybill and Boes (or download from Colorado University), refer to page 249 and 250.
Let Z be a standard normal and U be a chi-square distribution with n degrees of freedom, then we can prove X = Z/sqrt(U/n) is a t distribution using the transformation method:
The joint density of Z and U, 0

1/√2π  1/Γ(n/2)  (1/2)^(n/2) u^((k/2)-1) e^(-1/2 u) e^(-1/2 z^2 )

where Γ(n/2) is gamma function.

Make transformation X = Z/sqrt(U/n) and Y = U, the Jacobian is sqrt(y/n). The the joint density of X and Y is

√(y/n)  1/√2π  1/Γ(n/2)  (1/2)^(n/2) y^((k/2)-1) e^(-1/2 y) e^(-1/2 x^2 y/n)

Integrate the above wrt to y from -∞ to ∞ gives

Γ((n+1)/2)/Γ(n/2)   1/√nπ  1/(1+x^2/n)^((n+1)/2)

which is the density function of t-distribution.

Comment: I just made a few edits on your post, maybe you would like to take a look at them and use them to improve your answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for the correction.